# Trying to work with React v0.14.3 in the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I started in the React official tutorial but when I try to run the first example, it does not render or anything.

I'm running it in using Apache (Xampp htdocs). It doesn't show anything, even errors.

This question should've a duplicate but I can't find any. Also, I can't find any other tutorial that uses v0.14.3, I think, because those tutorials still imports JSXTransformer.js. I could be wrong.

So far this is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>React Tutorial</title>
    <script src="../bower_components/react/react.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/react/react-dom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
    var CommentList = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return (
                    <div className="commentList">
                    Hello, world! I am a CommentList.
            </div>
            );
        }
    });

    var CommentForm = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return (
                    <div className="commentForm">
                    Hello, world! I am a CommentForm.
            </div>
            );
        }
    });

    var CommentBox = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return (
                    <div className="commentBox">
                    <h1>Comments</h1>
                    <CommentList />
                    <CommentForm />
                    </div>
            );
        }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(
    <CommentBox />,
            document.getElementById('content')
    );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using script type `text/babel` you should include `babel` to your app, you can include it for example from public `cdn` (add it after `react-dom.js`), like this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
```

*However better use tools like [`webpack`](https://webpack.github.io/) or [`browserify`](http://browserify.org/)*